# Unable to create the "/home/zubair/htdocs/E-soft/cms/public/images" directory using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload image into the public folder, unfortunately, I am facing an error on how to fix it thanks. please help me

please see error https://flareapp.io/share/pPvYzYmy

**Controller**

```
public function Add_slider(Request $request){
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);
    return back()->with('success', 'Image Uploaded Successfully')->with('path', $new_name);
}
```

**HTML view**

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('add_slider.action')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">                      
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="header-title">Image Upload</h4>
                    <input type="file" name="image" class="dropify" data height="300" />
                </div> <!-- end card-body-->
            </div> <!-- end card-->
            <div class="page-title-right">
                <button type="submit" id="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light col-lg-1">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end col -->
    </div> <!-- end row --> 
</form>
```

Comment: `@mkdir` - from your screen. Try to get a certain error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need added write permission for public directory.

Can you try this command :

```
chmod -R 755 public
```